# Creating a column for a dataframe with exec() in pyspark is not working

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, exec

I have a dataframe with multiple columns, and I have created a code fragment to generate a new column 'label' which represents a string containing information of the rest of the columns.

Imagine I have the next dataframe 'df':

```
+------------+------+
| Atr0       | Atr1 |
+------------+------+
|     0      |  1   |
+------------+------+
|     0      |  2   |
+------------+------+
|     0      |  8   |
+------------+------+
|     ...    |  ... |
+------------+------+
```

So, I want to create a new dataframe 'df' which is:

```
+------------+------+-------------------+
| Atr0       | Atr1 |        Atr2       |  
+------------+------+-------------------+
|     0      |  1   | Atr0='0', Atr1='1'|
+------------+------+-------------------+
|     0      |  2   | Atr0='0', Atr1='2'|
+------------+------+-------------------+
|     0      |  8   | Atr0='0', Atr1='8'|
+------------+------+-------------------+
|     ...    |  ... |        ...        |
+------------+------+-------------------+
```

If I execute the next code fragment it works:

```
df = df.withColumn('Atr2', concat(lit("Atr0="), col('Atr0'), lit(", Atr1="), col('Atr1'))
```

But I want the code not to be user dependant. I mean, I have a variable 'list' containing the columns of the dataframe, so I want to iterate that list in order to generate the new column automatically. Here the code I generated:

```
def addColumn(list):

    # Many operations to create the dataframe 'df'
    list = list + ['AtrX']
    # list is a variable containing ['Atr0', 'Atr1', 'AtrX']
    label = "df = df.withColumn('label', concat("

    count_aux = 0
    for atributo_aux in list:
        if(count_aux == 0):
            label = label + "lit('" + atributo_aux + "='), col('" + atributo_aux + "')" 
        else:
            label = label + ", lit('," + atributo_aux + "='), col('" + atributo_aux + "')"
        count_aux += 1

    label = label + "))" 
    print(label)
    exec(label)
```

But when I execute the function the dataframe is never updated. I checked if the string was correctly generated and it is. Why if I execute the code putting manually the column names it is perfectly updated, and in the code generated above not?

Comment: Your aim is to generate new variable from all variables of your dataframe is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but utilizing exec() command of python...

Comment: your same code is working for me. Can you write `df.show()` after `exec(label)` and show the output?

Comment: My problem is that in my case, if I use exec, df is still containing only 2 columns (Atr0, and Atr1)... I have the code into a function

Comment: I think this code is correct. Check parameters you are passing to function and returning.

Comment: I will edit the question to show exactly what I have.

Comment: What are you returning from the function ?

Comment: Also, your list variable is containing all the columns of dataframe properly? I would avoid use of keyword name 'list' as a variable.